# Showing a set of box topologies is homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau_X) $ and $(Y, \tau_Y) $ be topological spaces. Consider $(X \times Y,\tau_{X \times Y}) $ and $(Y \times X, \tau_{Y \times X})$ where $\tau_{X \times Y}$ and $\tau_{Y \times X}$ are the product topologies. Prove that $X \times Y$ and $Y \times X $ are homeomorphic.

Attempt:

Well after processing the question the first thing that came to my mind was that i have to produce a function and then show that it is homeomorphic. So i propose this function:

$f(x,y) = (\pi_Y(x,y), \pi_X (x,y)) $ where $\pi_X (x,y) = x $ and $\pi_Y (x,y) = y$

Whose inverse is : $f^{-1}(x,y) = (\pi_X (x,y),\pi_Y(x,y)$

Now my argument is that this is a composition of continuous functions previously proven and as such it is a homeomorphism between the two spaces. Maybe it is doubt in my ability, but i feel that there should be more to this explanation. Should i come up with a different candidate? Could i get some hints if i am not correct in my proof before a full solution is written?

Comment: Just as a comment - it's perfectly acceptable to write $f(x,y)=(y,x)$.  If you like, you can then observe that $y=\pi_Y(x,y)$ and that $x=\pi_X(x, y)$, so it's clear that the maps are continuous.  Otherwise, what you've written is completely correct.

Comment: Your $f$ is not a composition in the usual sense. In order for your argument to work, you need to have proved already that if $f:X_1\to Y_1$ and $g:X_2\to Y_2$ are continuous, then the function from $X_1\times X_2$ to $Y_1\times Y_2$ that takes $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$ to $\langle f(x_1),g(x_2)\rangle$ is continuous. What you’re being asked to prove here is just a special case of that result. I suggest that you keep it simple and define $f(x,y)=\langle y,x\rangle$; then use the definition of the product topology to show directly that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: No, it’s not correct: the argument as presented relies on a (presumably unproved) general result to get a special case of that result.